# DIV - Same height jquery or css

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have this javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var leftHeight = $('#maincontent').height();
    $('#sidemenu').css({'height':leftHeight});
});
```

This works, but it is very limited. If my #sidemenu, is getting expanded (Example because of sub-menu), it become bigger inside the div.

How can I do so whenever #sidemenu or #maincontent for that matter, get's bigger (height increases), they follow each other.

If this can be done with CSS, I am open for this too.

Regards.

Comment: If this is for a layout, a CSS solution would probably be better.

Comment: I don't think you can attach an event to a DOM element to listens to variable change in attributes, You would have to write something like this by yourself.

Comment: Anyone with a .css solution then? Updated

Comment: posted a css/html solution. :) much better to use html/css than messing around with tricky javascript for this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget javascript.

Put `#sidemenu` into `#maincontent`, give it a fixed width and float it left. Then wrap everything in `#maincontent` (but not the `#sidebar`) into a div called `#wrapper` (lets say). Give `#wrapper` a width which equals the width of `#maincontent` minus the width of `#sidemenu` and float it left too. For good measure just before the closing `</div>` of `#maincontent` put `<br style="clear: both" />`.

Now `#maincontent` will expand to fit the sidemenu (if it needs to), but the content in `#maincontent` will also not wrap underneath the `#sidemenu` if its too short, as its in a wrapper div of its own.

Hope this helped.

## update

here is an example:

**html**

```
<div id="maincontent">
  <div id="sidemenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#asd">A Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#asd">A Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#asd">A Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#asd">A Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#asd">A Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div id="wrapper">
    This is where your text goes in the main content area of the site.
  </div>

  <br style="clear: both" />
</div>
```

**css**

```
#maincontent {
  width: 960px;
}

#sidemenu {
  width: 330px;
  float: left;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 660px;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: So what should I give a fixed with and float left. #sidemenu, or #maincontent?

Comment: I'll post an example, give me 5 mins.

Comment: I have posted an example. :) In my example #maincontent will be the height of whichever is taller out of #sidemenu and #wrapper.

Comment: Sorry, but when I try this code, the content of #wrapper is placed below the sidemenu, and not to the right. The divs must be aligned next to each other, in order for this to make sense.
Also, I am using a grid system.

Comment: I don't know why that happens, its probably wrapping, but it shouldn't do.